# Stable Diffusion ComfyUI Problem with IPAdapter and Clip_vision

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

It has to be some sort of compatibility issue with the IPadapters and the clip_vision but I don't know which one is the right model to download based on the models I have. I located these under clip_vision and the ipadaptermodels under /ipadapter so don't know why it does not work.

Error: Error occurred when executing IPAdapterApply: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode_image'

Error occurred when executing IPAdapterApply:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode_image'

File "C:\Users\Valknut\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 153, in recursive_execute
output_data, output_ui = get_output_data(obj, input_data_all)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Valknut\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 83, in get_output_data
return_values = map_node_over_list(obj, input_data_all, obj.FUNCTION, allow_interrupt=True)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Valknut\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 76, in map_node_over_list
results.append(getattr(obj, func)(**slice_dict(input_data_all, i)))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Valknut\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\ComfyUI_IPAdapter_plus\IPAdapterPlus.py", line 433, in apply_ipadapter
clip_embed = clip_vision.encode_image(image)
```

Really need help with this one.

I used all sorts of models `SD15` and `SDXL` restarted the UI but still did not work!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a outdated ComfyUI_IPAdapter_plus. See the bullet points under "Outdated ComfyUI or Extension" on the comfyUI_IPAdapter_plus troubleshooting page.

https://github.com/cubiq/ComfyUI_IPAdapter_plus/issues/108